# Initially Hiding and then Dynamically Adding and Removing Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a request form. It needs to list the study team members on a research study besides the PI and submitter of the form. However, some studies will have no additional team members so I would like the row to remain hidden until someone clicks the Add Team Member button.

What's working:
1. I've got the element hidden on initially loading the page. 
2. Clicking add rows adds the correct rows.
3. Clicking remove will remove a row.

Current problems:
1. If someone adds a team member then removes all the team members, clicking add team member will not add a row.
2. When the element is hidden on initial page load, the first time the Add Team Member button is clicked it adds two rows.

Here's my current code with only the relevant section of the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/test.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addTableRow(jQtable){
            jQtable.each(function(){
                var tds = '<tr>';
                jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function() {tds += '<td>'+$(this).html()+'</td>';});
                tds += '</tr>';
                if($('tbody', this).length > 0){$('tbody', this).append(tds);
                }else {$(this).append(tds);}
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function myDeleteFunction() {
            document.getElementById("stmember").deleteRow(0);
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#add').click(function() {
                $('#stmember').show();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        #stmember {
            display: none
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<h3><strong>Other Study Team Members:</strong></h3>
<FORM>
    <table id="stmember">
       <tr>
        <td>Name:
         <label for="namest1"></label>
        <input type="text" name="namest1" id="namest1" placeholder="First Name, Last Name" />
        </td>
        <td>JHED ID:
            <label for="jhedst1"></label>
            <input type="text" name="jhedst1" id="jhedst1" />
        </td>
        <td>Email:
            <label for="emailst1"></label>
            <input type="email" name="emailst1" id="emailst1" placeholder="you@example.com" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <CENTER>
    <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addTableRow($('#stmember'));">Add Study Team Member</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Remove Study Team Member</button>
    </CENTER>
</FORM> 
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, I'd fully commit to using that instead of mixing vanilla JS, as with jQuery you can use clone and remove effectively for what you're trying to achieve. Also, if you plan on submitting this as a form, please be sure to add [] to your input names so you can parse each row properly as the names are the same on the input fields. Please see the below snippet:

```js
function addTableRow() {
  var $tableRow = $('tr.model-row:first-child');
  var $clonedRow = $tableRow.clone().show();
  $('#stmember').append($clonedRow);
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
  var $memberTRs = $('tr', '#stmember');
  // If rowcount === 1, hide first row, don't remove it!!
  var rowCount = $memberTRs.length;
  if (rowCount === 1) {
    $('tr.model-row:first-child').hide();
    return;
  }
  $memberTRs.last().remove();
}

jQuery(function() {

  $('#delete').click(function() {
    myDeleteFunction();
  });

  $('#add').click(function() {
    addTableRow();
  });

});
```

```css
.model-row {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h3><strong>Other Study Team Members:</strong></h3>
  <FORM>
    <table id="stmember">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="model-row">
          <td>Name:
            <label for="namest1"></label>
            <input type="text" name="namest1[]" id="namest1" placeholder="First Name, Last Name" />
          </td>
          <td>JHED ID:
            <label for="jhedst1"></label>
            <input type="text" name="jhedst1[]" id="jhedst1" />
          </td>
          <td>Email:
            <label for="emailst1"></label>
            <input type="email" name="emailst1[]" id="emailst1" placeholder="you@example.com" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <CENTER>
      <button type="button" id="add">Add Study Team Member</button>
      <button type="button" id="delete">Remove Study Team Member</button>
    </CENTER>
  </FORM>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple solutions for you:

**Solution 1**

Store the HTML of the row in your addTableRow function within a variable. That way you can use tokens for the input IDs to ensure they are unique. Also, you won't have to provide the first row in your HTML, as it will be created through your JS function. Something like:

```
var template = "<tr><td>Name:<label for="namest1"></label><input type="text" name="namest!!TOKEN!!" id="namest!!TOKEN!!" placeholder="First Name, Last Name" /></td><td>JHED ID:<label for="jhedst1"></label><input type="text" name="jhedst!!TOKEN!!" id="jhedst!!TOKEN!!" /></td><td>Email:<label for="emailst1"></label><input type="email" name="emailst!!TOKEN!!" id="emailst!!TOKEN!!" placeholder="you@example.com" /></td></tr>";
```

**Solution 2**

Use a templating engine like [jsRender](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrender) or [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

**Conclusion**

The cleanest method would be to use a templating engine, if you're game for that. But using a string to store the template within your function will work.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a row, you use the last existing row to create it. But if you remove all the row you lose your example of row.

You can easily fix your problem by checking when you remove a Row, if it's the last one, add a new row before remove the last one.